# can i capture root directory's requests by writing .htaccess file in subdirectory???

Tags: php, jquery, apache, .htaccess

all
   I have directory named "/home/pradeep/xxx/yyy
   I have placed my php pages in "yyy" directory
   My document root is "/home/pradeep/"
   I have written a .htaccess file in "yyy" directory.
   My ajax url is www.domain.com/api. I want to get that response in my php file in "yyy" directory.
   So i want either to capture the root url requests or i have to capture url requests in javascript before the ajax is being called.( * I cant modify my javascript file from where ajax calls are being called, i can't place .htaccess in root directory "/home/pradeep")

q:? how to capture www.domain.com/api requests and responses in side my sub-directory and manipulate that with the help of .htaccess ??

Comment: That doesn't make a great deal of sense. Could you edit it to make what you're trying to do clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't unfortunatly, if you want to capture request for url like www.domain.com/api you will need to either put an htaccess in /home/pradeep/ or in /home/pradeep/api/. (assuming that www.domain.com point to /home/pradeep/)

Comment: cant i capture the requests i.e. in jquery like before the ajax/jsonrpc requests starts for processing request

Comment: You maybe able to do so using JQuery $.ajaxPrefilter() function (I have never used it but I think it should fix your issue)